# Exactly who knows about PAST & FUTURE of human beings except Allah and Hazrat Muhammad S.A.W.W?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

AOA !

I have watched a TV show in which a Molana was telling a story of some "Peer" (person which is religious and people follow him) . He said a Lion came to him and talked to him and after that he said that "Peer" knows about all Past and Future. So here is my question that only Allah and Hazrat Muhammad S.A.W.W knows about future and past even once Hazrat Muhammad S.A.W.W said "By God I know the names of those warriors who will come to fight with Dajjal and I even know names of their forefathers and colors of their horses". Because Allah has given special knowledge to HIM S.A.W.W . But I am sure that no one else can see Past and Future. But I have not enough knowledge to talk about this matter so please if anyone knows any reference to prove then please let me know.

Jazak Allah.

Comment: I doubt the Prophet (SAW) himself knew the future except for the specific parts Allah taught him in light of the verse 7:188.

Comment: [31:34](https://quran.com/31/34).

Comment: Yes only few not all future.

Answer (score 3):

None knows about this except Allah or through Allah's revelation. Even Muhammad's () knowledge on the matter is limited on what was revealed to him as Allah says:

> Say, "None in the heavens and earth knows the unseen except Allah , and they do not perceive when they will be resurrected."
>   ([27:65](https://legacy.quran.com/27/65))

Comment: Yes of course only few events.

Answer (score 0):

According to Quran:

> He is the Knower of the Unseen and does not disclose His Unseen to anyone, except only to a Messenger that He has chosen, and He sends guardians before him and behind him. (72:26,72:27)

Only God Knows everything **BUT** he can teach whatever he wants to whoever he wants.